# В строке нужно заменить каждую гласную по след. принципу: Ввод - привет, Вывод - призивезет

Tags: python, строки

```
s = str (input())
b = ('а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'е')
for i in s:
    if i in b:
        s = s.replace(i, i+'з'+i,)
print(s)
```

Comment: Что не так с вашим решением? Это должно быть объяснено в вопросе. Ну то есть я то знаю, в чём проблема, но если вы хотите получить ответ на вопрос, нужно давать всю информацию в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Можно применить метод `.translate()` с предварительным созданием таблицы замены символов через `str.maketrans()`

```
s = 'привет'
mytable = str.maketrans({k: f'{k}з{k}' for k in 'ауоыиэюяе'})
print(s.translate(mytable))
```

```
призивезет
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает

Answer (score 1):

можно оставить просто цикл по гласным

```
s = str (input())
b = ('а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'е')
for i in b:
    s = s.replace(i, i+'з'+i)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input()
for i in string:
    if i in 'ауоыиэяюе':
        string = string.replace(i, i + 'з' + i)
print(string)
```

`input()` изначально на вход принимает строку, поэтому не нужно ещё раз преобразовывать значение в строку с помощью `str()`, исправил название переменной, чтобы лучше читалось

Comment: Проблема кода не в этом. Попробуйте ввести любое слово с повторяющимися гласными, например 'перебор'

Comment: Извиняюсь, спасибо, что указали на ошибку